# What does { } do within a string?

Tags: php

```
$name = "jason";
$p = "hello-{hello2}-$name-{$name}";
echo $p;
```

output :

```
hello-{hello2}-jason-jason
```

Came across some examples of prepared statements and noticed this. If its encompassing a variable, it removes them, otherwise it keeps them. Why is this behavior necessary when

```
echo "$name";
```

gets you the same result as

```
echo "{$name}";
```

or is it just readability?

Comment: It is used to separate variable from a string, in a case like `echo "I like {$str}s a lot"; ` it wont be possible to do this w/o using {} syntax.

Comment: Mind you: if you came across those in _"prepared statement"_, chances are, they are not _real_ prepared statements.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's used as a delimiter for variables in strings. This is necessary in some cases, as PHP's string parser isn't Greedy aand will mis-interpret many common structs.

e.g.

```
$foo = array();
$foo['bar'] = array();
$foo['bar']['baz'] = 'qux';

echo "Hello $foo[bar][baz]";
```

will actually print

```
Hello Array[baz]
```

Because it's parsed as

```
echo "Hello ", $foo['bar'], "[baz]";
        ^          ^           ^
      string     array       string
```

Using `{}` forces PHP to consider the array reference as single entity:

```
echo "Hello, {$foo['bar']['baz']}";  // prints "Hello, qux"
```

It also helps differentiate ambiguous stuff

```
$foo = 'bar';

echo "$foos" // undefined variable 'foos'
echo "{$foo}s" // variable containing 'bar' + string 's'
```

Comment: Beat me by second, nice.

Comment: echo "Hello, {$foo['bar']['baz']}";  Boom goes the dynamite! Makes sense, I can see why they did that now. You win the green checkmark for providing code examples. Thank you!

Comment: Just realized you have 200k reputation. Ive been looking for someone to ask : do you feel you know everything about php? Ive been studying it for a long time, and it seems overwhelming, the amount of stuff there is to know, the 'gotchas', the subtlety. Do you memorize functions, parameters or do you still lookup alot of things? I have to look almost everything. I know that x CAN be done, but not always exactly which combination of objects / functions would be best to do that. Also, do you write more procedural or oop code? Im about 50/50. Anyway, thank you again for answering my orig question.

Comment: heck no, I KNOW I don't know everything. I still learn stuff from the most basic/obvious of questions/answers here. most of php's functions are trivially discoverable. Best tip: looking for a function? use `http://php.net/nameoffunction`. if it's not quite right, you'll get a list of suggestions that invariably will have what you need, or something close to it that WILL lead to what you need.

Answer (score 4):

It's something called "complex syntax"

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/pl/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) you can go to *Complex (curly) syntax* section and see many examples.

> Complex (curly) syntax
>
> This isn't called complex because the syntax is complex, but because it allows for the use of complex expressions.
>
> Any scalar variable, array element or object property with a string representation can be included via this syntax. Simply write the expression the same way as it would appear outside the string, and then wrap it in { and }. Since { can not be escaped, this syntax will only be recognised when the $ immediately follows the {. Use {\$ to get a literal {$.
>
> Functions, method calls, static class variables, and class constants inside {$} work since PHP 5. However, the value accessed will be interpreted as the name of a variable in the scope in which the string is defined. Using single curly braces ({}) will not work for accessing the return values of functions or methods or the values of class constants or static class variables.

Answer (score 1):

It does not necessarily generate the same output:

```
$name = 'foo';
$names = 'bar';

echo "Output1: $names";
echo "Output2: {$name}s";
```

Output

```
Output1: bar
Output2: foos
```

Also you can access complex structures via the curly syntax like `{$foo->bar}`.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is useful when you want to display variable following some string and you don't want any space between them.

Compare the following:

```
<?php

$name='John';

echo "My name is $nameathan. I'm twenty years old<br />";
echo "My name is {$name}athan. I'm twenty years old<br />";
```

It will give you result:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: nameathan in ... on line 5
My name is . I'm twenty years old
My name is Johnathan. I'm twenty years old
```

For first echo it will generate notice and won't work as expected because PHP doesn't know that you want to use variable `$name` in the string and not `$nameathan`. Using curly braces in second case solves the issue.

Of course you can concatenate string this way:

```
echo "My name is $name"."athan. I'm twenty years old<br />";
```

and it also solves the issue but if you have many such variables in string it will be much more convenient to use curly braces.